# Setting Tasker app to disable one finger touch after opening a specific app?

Tags: tasker

I need to disable one finger touch (2 or more fingers touch is still allowed) after opening an app. Can I use Tasker app to do it ?

Comment: I doubt it. But you might check the [Tasker User Guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/) to prove otherwise.